# Update com Soma e Subtração Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou começando a aprender a usar a `Framework Laravel 5.4` para isso estou fazendo um sistema de finanças pessoal e tenho uma tabela de `Conta` com o campo (`Saldo`);

Gostaria de ao fazer uma transação de *Credito* ou *Debito* que irá **Subtrair** ou **Somar** o valor de `Saldo` com o ***valor a transação***.

Sei fazer isso em SQL, mas qual é a melhor forma de fazer isso no Laravel?

Comment: Poste como você faria isso em SQL.

Comment: $Somar = DB::update('UPDATE conta SET saldo = saldo + ? WHERE Cliente_id =  1', ['Valor']);

Comment: mas não sei se é a melhor forma, estou estou Usando Repositories para update e create, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem duas formas que pode ser implementado isso uma delas é pelo [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent)  [ORM Model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent) e a outra [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries)

- [Eloquent ORM Model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent)

Crie uma classe para representar sua tabela da seguinte forma:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;    
class Conta extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'conta';
    protected $fillable = ['cliente_id','saldo'];
    public $timestamps = false;    

    public function setSomaSaldo($saldo)
    {
        // Conta Existente
        if ($this->exists)
        {
            $this->attributes['saldo'] =
                $this->attributes['saldo'] + $saldo;
            $this->save();
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function setSubtrairSaldo($saldo)
    {
        // Conta Existente
        if ($this->exists)
        {
            $this->attributes['saldo'] =
                $this->attributes['saldo'] - $saldo;
            $this->save();
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

que irá conter dois métodos um para somar saldo e a outra para subtrair o saldo, seguindo que a conta existe para que esses dois métodos funcionem. Para utilizar os métodos faça:

- ***Somando***:

  ```
  $client_id = 1;
  $saldo = 150.69;
  $d = App\Models\Conta::where('cliente_id', $client_id)->first();
  if ($d) 
  {
      $d->setSomaSaldo($saldo);
  }
  ```
- ***Subtraindo***:

  ```
  $client_id = 1;
  $saldo = 150.69;
  $d = App\Models\Conta::where('cliente_id', $client_id)->first();
  if ($d) 
  {
      $d->setSubtrairSaldo($saldo);
  }
  ```

nesse método `setSomaSaldo($saldo)` irá agregar o valor e depois salvar na tabela a alteração, e isso acontece também no `setSubtrairSaldo($saldo)` que subtrair o valor do saldo atual e salvas as alterações.

---

- [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries)

Pelo método [increment/decrement](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#increment-and-decrement) você pode somar ou subtrair pelo [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries) de forma simples e com excelente desempenho:

- ***Somando***:

  ```
  $client_id = 1;
  $saldo = 150.69;
  $status = \DB::table('conta')
         ->where('cliente_id',$client_id)
         ->increment('saldo', $saldo);
  if ($status) // atualizado com sucesso
  {
  }
  ```
- ***Subtraindo***:

  ```
  $client_id = 1;
  $saldo = 150.69;
  $status = \DB::table('conta')
         ->where('cliente_id',$client_id)
         ->decrement('saldo', $saldo);
  if ($status) // atualizado com sucesso
  {
  }
  ```

***Observação:*** *aqui também funciona a classe [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) com [Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries) do mesmo jeito observe:*

- ***Somando***:

  ```
  App\Models\Conta::where('cliente_id', $cliente_id)
               ->increment('saldo', $saldo);
  ```
- ***Subtraindo***:

  ```
  App\Models\Conta::where('cliente_id', $cliente_id)
               ->decrement('saldo', $saldo);
  ```

---

No seu comentário foi utilizado um [Running Raw SQL Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#running-queries) que também é uma ótima solução, **exemplo**:

```
$client_id = 1;
$saldo = 150.69;
$params = [$saldo, $client_id];
\DB::update('UPDATE `conta` SET saldo = saldo + ? WHERE Cliente_id = ?', $params);
```

***Observações:*** os dois últimos ([Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries) e [Running Raw SQL Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#running-queries)) tem um desempenho melhor que o primeiro, porque, o primeiro executa 2 `SQL` para realizar a operação e os dois últimos apenas 1 `SQL` já realiza a operação, mas, vale lembrar que em muitos casos a primeira seria a mais recomendável, exemplo inserções e atualizações comuns, então, fica a seu critério qual das 3 soluções podem ser utilizadas.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Eloquent - ORM Model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent)
- [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries)
- [Database: Query Builder methods: increment/decrement](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#increment-and-decrement)

Comment: Fiz a 2 para teste e funcionou perfeitamente, vou testar as outras e ver oque vai se enquadra melhor na minha aplicação, muito grato.