# Insert Many To Many Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3, relacionamento

Tenho uma situação da seguinte forma. Tenho 4 tabelas users -> departamento -> categoria_departamento -> categoria -> postagems
Onde na minha view eu tenho um select onde mostra uma relação de dados sobre departamento ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essas informações já vem do banco de dados.
Tenho também outro select referente a categoria veja um ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então quando eu for fazer o cadastro do Artigo, ele tem que guardar essas informações na tabela pivo que no caso é categoria_departamento.
Essa tabela faz relacionamento ManyToMany com as tabelas Departamentos e Categoria.

No meu código esta assim:

```
    $departamento = new Departamento();
    $categoria = new Categoria();
    $postagem = new Postagem();
    $findCat = $categoria->where('id' , $request->categoria)->get()->first();
    $findDep = $departamento->where('id' , $request->departamento)->get()->first();

    $findCat->departamentos()->attach([
        'departamento_id'   =>  $findDep->id,
        'categoria_id'      =>  $findCat->id,
    ]);

         $postagem->categoria_id = $request->categoria;
         $postagem->titulo = $request->titulo;
         $postagem->imagem = $filename;
         $postagem->descricao = $request->descricao;
         $postagem->status = $request->status;
         $result = $postagem->save();
```

Ate ai tudo bem. mais ele esta salvando os id certo no campo ta tabela pivo certa mais depois ele grava mais uma linha veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que pode ser isso ai?

Outra coisa se existir uma maneira mais fácil de se fazer podem dizer por que eu nunca fiz um sistema de postagem na minha vida.

Imagem da tabela as 4 ultimas imagens da tabela são as que eu quero

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não deu certo a resposta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando se tem um relacionamento **muitos** para **muitos** com o  [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) e utiliza o método `attach` para adicionar itens na tabela itermediária não precisa passar no seu caso especifico o código da chave de categoria, como está sendo navegado pela relações, o próprio código do [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) já tem essa chave e só precisa passar o código do departamento, é por isso da duplicação de linhas, exemplo de como seria um código, porque, também tem alguns problemas no seu ***código primário***:

```
$departamento = new Departamento();
$categoria = new Categoria();
$postagem = new Postagem();

$findCat = $categoria->where('id',$request->categoria)
                     ->first();
$findDep = $departamento->where('id',$request->departamento)
                     ->first();

if ($findCat && $findDep) // se os dois existem
{
    $findCat->departamentos()
        ->attach($findDep); // adiciona um item a solução
}

$postagem->categoria_id = $request->categoria;
$postagem->titulo = $request->titulo;
$postagem->imagem = $filename;
$postagem->descricao = $request->descricao;
$postagem->status = $request->status;
$result = $postagem->save();
```

ou seja, o `attach` pela documentação aceita um código que identifica a chave da outra tabela. Existe o `sync` que aceita um `array` simples [como descrito na sua documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) e pode ser útil na ***inserção e controle*** de ***remoção*** dos itens da sua tabela intermediária, ou seja, é responsável por remover os itens que não existem no `array` e estão presentes na sua tabela e confirma aqueles que não existem e estão presente no `array`, ***exemplo***:

```
if ($findCat && $findDep) // se os dois existem
{
    $findCat->departamentos()
        ->attach([1,2,3,4]); // sincroniza os itens
}
```

<sub>***Post e Links para leitura***</sub>

- [Relacionamento muitos para muitos laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/relacionamento-muitos-para-muitos-laravel)
- [Problemas com relacionamento um para muitos laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152089/problemas-com-relacionamento-um-para-muitos-laravel)
- [Resultado nome do campo ao inves do id no Laravel 5?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212234/resultado-nome-do-campo-ao-inves-do-id-no-laravel-5)
- [Update com Soma e Subtração Laravel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/233677/update-com-soma-e-subtra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-laravel)

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)
- [Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)
- [Inserting & Updating Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)