# Cadastra N pra 1 e N pra N?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

Como posso fazer para cadastrar em um relacionamento **1 pra N** e de **N pra M**, estou fazendo desta maneira, ***mas não está legal***:

```
$endereco = new endereco;
$endereco->complemento = $request->complemento;
$endereco->logradouro = $request->logradouro;
$endereco->bairro = $request->bairro;
$endereco->cidade = $request->cidade;
$endereco->estado = $request->estado;
$endereco->cep = $request->cep;
$endereco->save();   

$civil = new civil;
$civil->nome = $request->nome;
$civil->cpf = $request->cpf;
$civil->matricula = $request->matricula;
$civil->data_nascimento = $request->data_nascimento;
$civil->pai = $request->pai;
$civil->mae = $request->mae;
$civil->situacao = $request->situacao;
$civil->sexo = $request->sexo;
$civil->matricula = $request->matricula;
$civil->estado_civil = $request->estado_civil;
$endereco->civil()->save($civil);
```

Comment: O que seria legal?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/236486/insert-many-to-many-laravel-5-4/236600#236600 um exemplo

Comment: Já percebi que você tem algumas perguntas, mas, não interage com a comunidade, porque?

Comment: Desculpa.
É que não sei como devo fazer. Se for seguir esse padrão o código vai ficar muito grande. sem falar que não consigo fazer a relação de muitos pra muitos no laravel. Se puder me ajudar serei muito grato.

Comment: você precisa disponibilizar as duas classes! para que eu possa ver, não me parece dificil resolver, mas, eu não sei o que você fez nas classes model! e você tem perguntas em aberto, é bom interagir e creditar se resolver seus problemas, ajuda e muito outras pessoas

Answer (score 0):

Se nao estou em erro, a chave do endereço fica do lado do civil. A sequencia das entidades está corecta, mas vejo um problema na linha: `$endereco->civil()->save($civil);`. 
Se deseja "setar" o codigo do endereço deve vir algo como `$civil->endereco_id = $endereco->id;` e por fim `$civil->save();`

Aconselho a veres sobre **Eloquent Relationships em** https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships